# FetchError: Invalid JSON Response Body in Twitter API Search

Tags: node.js, json, express, twitter

I'm trying to build a Twitter bot using the Twitter API, and I'm getting a FetchError with the message 'invalid JSON response body'. I'm using Node.js and the 'twitter-lite' library to search for recent tweets with the '#keyword' hashtag, and then follow the users who tweeted those tweets. The error occurs when the bot tries to make the search request to the Twitter API. I've included the full error message below:

`FetchError: invalid json response body at https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets?q=%23keyword&count=10&result_type=recent&lang=en reason: Unexpected end of JSON input`

I'm not sure what's causing this error or how to fix it. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const passport = require('passport');
const TwitterStrategy = require('passport-twitter').Strategy;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./config');

const params = {
  q: '#keyword',
  count: 10,
  result_type: 'recent',
  lang: 'en'
};

let trustProxy = false;
if (process.env.DYNO) {
  trustProxy = true;
}

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(session({ secret: '', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true, maxAge: 30000 }));

passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
  consumerKey: config.consumer_key,
  consumerSecret: config.consumer_secret,
  callbackURL: `${config.herokuURL}/auth/twitter/callback`
},
function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
  // Placeholder callback function - this can be updated to handle the authenticated user as needed
  return done(null, profile);
}));

// Get an access token and secret for the authenticated user
const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: config.consumer_key,
  consumer_secret: config.consumer_secret,
  access_token_key: config.access_token_key,
  access_token_secret: config.access_token_secret,
  extension: false,
});

// Use setInterval to run the Twitter API search and follow loop at a set interval
setInterval(() => {
  client.get('search/tweets', params)
    .then(data => {
      const tweets = data.statuses
        .map(tweet => ({ id: tweet.id_str, user_id: tweet.user.id_str }));

      console.log(`Found ${tweets.length} tweets`);
      for (let i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function (tweets, i) {
          client.post('friendships/create', { user_id: tweets[i].user_id })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(`Followed: https://twitter.com/${response.screen_name}`);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err[0].message ? err[0].message : err);
            });
        }, 2164000, tweets, i);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}, 2164000);

// Handle GET requests to the root route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.end('started');
});

// Initialize Passport and restore authentication state, if any, from the session
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Route for initiating the Twitter authentication flow
app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

// Route for handling the Twitter callback
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect to the dashboard or another appropriate route
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  });

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: What library are you using for interacting with the API? I don't see the `Twitter` class imported

Comment: I left off the first line of the code in the transfer. I am using TwitterLite and ```const Twitter = require('twitter-lite');```